# Prevent globalization culture changes across request

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, webforms

- WebForms, .NET 4.61

I am having an issue where dates are not converting from strings.

```
public dsBookingActual GetBookingActualData(Int64 ozBookingID, string consultant, string screenViewed)
{
            DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_GetBookingActualData");
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OzBookingID", DbType.Int64, ozBookingID);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Consultant", DbType.String, consultant);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ScreenViewed", DbType.String, screenViewed);

            dsBookingActual dsBA = new dsBookingActual();
            //LoadDataSet fails when the date is 29/01/2016
            db.LoadDataSet(dbCommand, dsBA, new string[] { Constant.BOOKING_ACTUAL, "Passengers" });
            return dsBA;
}
```

We are in AU so the date format is dd/mm/yyyy and converting dates of 29/01/2016 fail as it is being attempted as mm/dd/yyyy for instance and 29 is not a valid month.

I tracked it down to the fact that the language settings in the browser are set to US similair to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773842/culture-changing-inexplicably-during-asp-net-web-application-request).

We have a globailzation tag in **system.web** as:

```
<globalization culture="en-AU" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" uiCulture="en-AU" />
```

So my question is how do I **prevent** the culture changing across the request. I am guessing it involves not acknowledging or processing the "Accept-Language header in the HTTP Request" but I am unsure how to implement this.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: "I am having an issue where dates are not converting from strings" can you show the code where this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this issue was as a consequence of our usage of [ASP Boilerplate](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/). Nothing wrong with the framework, it was our usage of it that was causing the issue.